# php mail() not working correct

Tags: php, email

I try to send a mail with php and the mail() function. I got the right smtp and port.

```
<?php 
$header = 'From: mail\r\n'; 
$success = mail('mail', 'test', 'test', $header); 
if ($success){
   echo 'yes';
} else {
   echo 'no';
}
?>
```

I wanted to see if it's worked or not but It's not working. Can anyone tell me why or how I can fix it?

Comment: do you get any error message or just the `$success` is false ?

Comment: Is the code running from the server network, or from your home, work(development) network ?

Comment: @Natsathorn just the $success is false (no error)

Comment: @Accountantم from the server network